# HL2/Source Dedicated Server on Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac

Has anyone ever managed to host a HL or Source dedicated server?
I can install both from Steam tools, but they simply don't work at all.

Half-Life Dedicated server:

-Failed to start game (missing executable)

Source Dedicated server doesn't do anything.

There is a documentation for setting a [Source Dedicated Server](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Dedicated_Server) using [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD):

```
Logged in OK
Waiting for license info...OK

Steam>force_install_dir ./HL2/

Steam>app_update 232370 validate
ERROR! Failed to install app '232370' (Invalid platform)

Steam>force_install_dir ./HLS/

Steam>app_update 255470 validate
ERROR! Failed to install app '255470' (Invalid platform)
```

Comment: Need more info. Don't make us search for what you are talking about. Give details of what you've tried. Show us that you have researched the problem before posting here. Show us your work.

Comment: Did that ever support mac OS or is it just for OS X?

Comment: @Hennes I tried this in Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: SteamCMD isn’t for modders, the guide is. But it’ll suffice, so fire away. The SteamCMD documentation contains information on OS X, dunno whether it was added recently.

Comment: @DanielB Fire away what?

Comment: Use the guide. Which you did. Then you didn't Google. [You need to log in](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#ERROR.21_Failed_to_install_app_.27xxxxxx.27_.28No_subscription.29).

Comment: @DanielB Logged in OK